# Shell script problems: how to parse a special "word" out of a line of xml file

Tags: xml, shell, parsing, ubuntu

i need really your help. I have a xml-log file, which content information, that i have to parse.

Such xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results>
<error file="mixed.cpp" line="11" id="unreadVariable" severity="style" msg="Variable 'wert' is assigned a value that is never used."/>
<error file="*" line="0" id="unmatchedSuppression" severity="style" msg="Unmatched suppression: missingIncludeSystem"/>
</result>
```

I have to parse it into a html table. I created a blanco html:
     
    
    Error summary

```
<thead>
<tr> 
<th>Filename</th>
<th>Line</th>
<th>Testname</th>
<th>Severity</th>
<th>Severity_description</th>
</tr>
</thead> 

<tbody> 

</table>
```

So i try to read out of xml **mixed.cpp** to fill it into th **Filename**

This is my shell script for it (only for Filename, cause it still doesn´t work):

```
#!/bin/bash

INPUT=./static-code-analysis.xml
OUTPUT=./mixed_output.html
LINE_XML=3
while read LINE_XML
   do
      FILENAME=$(grep 'error file' $LINE_XML | awk -F\" '{print $2}')
      sed '/<tbody>/ a <tr> <td>$FILENAME</td> </tr>'       
$OUTPUT >abc
done < $INPUT
```

I want to go throw all lines an find in every line the pre-word **error file** and than cut out place **mixed.cpp** and save it in FILENAME.

Unfortunately it doesn´t work. FILENAME is still empty and i can´t really fill the html.

can somebody say me where i stuck?

thanks a lot ;)

Comment: Sure, you could write a fragile shell script that tries to interpret XML but breaks even when the XML format remains exactly the same. But you could also do it right and use XSLT which is specifically designed to do this exact thing in a standardized, robust way!

Comment: I notice you set `LINE_XML=3` but then use it as if it were a filename in `... grep 'error file' $LINE_XML ` right? I don't see that working. Learn to debug, take complex lines like that apart and see each cmd up to a `|` char work OK on the cmd-line, *then* add the next chunk. Also `set -x` will show you each line of code with the variable values expanded. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given an XSLT template like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/results">
      <html>
      <body>
      <table>
      <thead>
      <tr>
      <th>Filename</th>
      <th>Line</th>
      <th>Testname</th>
      <th>Severity</th>
      <th>Severity_description</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="error"/>
      </tbody>

      </table>
      </body>
      </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="error">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@file"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@line"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@severity"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="@msg"/></td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

...and an `errors.xml` like so (I had to fix your original syntax, which used `results` in one place and `result` in another):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results>
<error file="mixed.cpp" line="11" id="unreadVariable" severity="style" msg="Variable 'wert' is assigned a value that is never used."/>
<error file="*" line="0" id="unmatchedSuppression" severity="style" msg="Unmatched suppression: missingIncludeSystem"/>
</results>
```

...the following command:

```
xsltproc template.xsl errors.xml
```

...emits an HTML file that looks like what you're asking for.

Comment: Hey, you are the best man! i never thought it´s that simple. But i have a question: how can i bind a css stylesheet to xsl file? cause there is a problem with it?

Comment: I'd have to see how you're doing it, and what the problem is, before I can comment. Might be worth asking as a separate question.